# How can I best use my time as a Mathematical sciences PhD student in the UK

Tags: phd

I would like some useful advice regarding pursuing a PhD in mathematical sciences in the UK. I've just started my PhD in mathematical modelling and would like to know as much as possible about how to make the most of the entire journey. I have some ideas here and there but I want to know what things to do and things to avoid, planning ahead, useful websites etc.

Topic/Question have been edited to broaden scope of question.

Comment: I've not heard about books, but many departments have a graduate student handbook. But I don't think that's quite what you're looking for.

Comment: @ Chris C, not quite what I'm looking for. I'm more interested in books like-How to Get a PhD: A Handbook for Students and Their Supervisors, Your PhD Companion, etc. I just need a recommendation before getting any of them.

Comment: I find it hard (even narrowed to the UK) to believe that the answers to this question will not vary significantly by field and/or by institution. Could you narrow down your focus?

Comment: @John Normally these kinds of 'lists' questions are discouraged on this site. That said, I do think it is a valuable question. Perhaps an edit could turn the question into something where the answer would not change over time (as new books/articles are published). Might I propose "How can I maximize my time during my PhD in ____ science in the UK?" Besides books and articles, inside the brains of the members here there is a wealth of information.

Comment: @earthling, thanks for the very useful suggestion, I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: I changed the title; "maximize my time" would mean that you want to take as long as possible to graduate.

Answer (score 1):

As a recently-started science PhD student myself, I can recommend:

```
The Research Student’s Guide To Success
Pat Cryer
Pub Open University Press, 2006
ISBN: 0 335 22117 3
```